# SQLAlchemy Update Operation Gives MySQL Error 1292

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to update a record in a SQLAlchemy table using it's ORM. Here is the query that I am writing:

```
localsession.query(Experiment).\
                 filter(Experiment.UserExperimentNumber==ExperimentId).\
                 filter(Experiment.UserId==UserId).\
                 update({Experiment.ExperimentStatus: Experiment.ExperimentStatus - "Approved"})
```

This gives me an Operational error with MySQL's error code 1292. Following is the error message:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'ForReview'") 'UPDATE `Experiment` SET `ExperimentStatus`=(`Experiment`.`ExperimentStatus` - %s) WHERE `Experiment`.`UserExperimentNumber` = %s AND `Experiment`.`UserId` = %s' ('Approved', '102', '1')
```

I tried looking for the MySQL error mentioned and it seems that the error is being caused by the `AND` statement in `WHERE` of the MySQL query.

How should I correct this? Is there some other reason behind the error? I understand that I could just as well write the query without the ORM layer but I would like to avoid that because I have used the ORM throughout the application. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that expression `Experiment.ExperimentStatus - "Approved"` is right? What does minus sign mean in this case?

Comment: You are right. That line was the mistake. I should have been using `update({Experiment.ExperimentStatus: new_status})`. Changed that and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the way I was providing the update value in the last line of the query. I changed it to `update({Experiment.ExperimentStatus: "Approved"})` and it worked.